# Activate JProgressBar only during a method

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, jprogressbar

I'm having troubles using `JProgressBar`. I have a function that can take some time, and I want a progress bar on indeterminate mode while the function is being executed. I have a button that activates this function, and I've tried to `setIndeterminate(true)` before calling the function, and after that, `setIndeterminate(false)`, but i don't get the progress bar moving at any time.

I have this code:

```
        progBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        //delay(12);
        //this.setEnabled(false);
        Executor executor = java.util.concurrent.Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {@Override
            public void run() {
                    function1();

            }});

        //progBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        //progBar.setVisible(false);
        System.out.println("End Function");
        //-........................
    }
```

Also tried the `function1()` without any new executor. If I don't comment the line `setIndeterminate(false)`, the progress bar doesn't start, but if I comment it, it always is on indeterminate mode.

Note that I'm using the Netbeans IDE to design some GUI, but coding most of the things myself (Only using NetBeans GUI for positioning).

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a **`SwingWorker`** for long running tasks.
See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably move this code:

```
progBar.setIndeterminate(false);
progBar.setVisible(false);
```

into a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` block after calling `function1()`.

The way it's set up now it will execute immediately after the `setIndeterminate(true)` call - that `execute()` method does not block.

For example:

```
executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                function1();
                // now fix the progress bar
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    progBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                    progBar.setVisible(false);
                });
        }});
```

Comment: Ok, it worked for me. Well, setIntermediate(false) is executed a little before the function ends, but not a problem.

Thank you!!